# Google pie charts add rows - pie chart didn't rendered

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-pie-chart

I have this JS file in asp.netcore. I'm trying to generate a pie chart from my database and there is only 1 row of data. I'm not getting any errors but only the title gets rendered but not pie chart.
My JS code

```
google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Index?handler=GlobalChartData',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        type: 'GET',
        success: MyChart
    });
    function MyChart(globalData) {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(globalData);
        data.addColumn('string', 'GlobalCases');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Data');
        data.addRows([
            ['NewConfirmed', globalData.NewConfirmed],
            ['NewDeaths', globalData.NewDeaths],
            ['NewRecovered', globalData.NewRecovered],
            ['TotalConfirmed', globalData.TotalConfirmed],
            ['TotalDeaths', globalData.TotalDeaths],
            ['TotalRecovered', globalData.TotalRecovered]
        ]);
        var options = { 'title': 'Global Covid Data' };
        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('ChartForGlobal'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    };
}
```

my c# code

```
public JsonResult OnGetGlobalChartData()
        {
            var globalData = _context.GlobalContexts.ToList();
            return new JsonResult(globalData);
        }
```

[image: Returned Data Image]

Edit:
In add rows, globalData.NewConfirmed -> NewConfirmed is undefined and so are the others.

Comment: Check in browser console there might be some error

Comment: Hi @Swati I don't see any error in f12. The only error there is localhost/favicon.ico:1

Comment: I have tested this on my end only change i have made is this `globalData.NewConfirmed` i have change it to `Number(globalData.NewConfirmed)` and same for other as well and then it was working fine .

Comment: Hi @Swati. This still didn't solve anything. My pie chart was not generated and no error thrown in f12 as well.

Comment: Check this working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dshtbg2q/) .

Comment: Hi @Swati Please check the Edit. My data to be added is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my add rows to

```
for (var i = 0; i < globalData.length; i++)
        {
            data.addRows([
                ['NewConfirmed', Number(globalData[i].NewConfirmed)],
                ['NewDeaths', Number(globalData[i].NewDeaths)],
                ['NewRecovered', Number(globalData[i].NewRecovered)],
                ['TotalConfirmed', Number(globalData[i].TotalConfirmed)],
                ['TotalDeaths', Number(globalData[i].TotalDeaths)],
                ['TotalRecovered', Number(globalData[i].TotalRecovered)]
            ]);
        }
```

Now my chart is generated.
Thank you @Swati.